# In Rest API 2.0 is it possible to get some meta fields but not others?

Tags: rest-api

So - I am using register_post_meta() to register the meta field for my custom post type so it shows in Rest call with the basic url wp-json/wp/v2/my_custom_post_type_rest_handle. My next step is to add a second meta field. The thing is I do not need both fields in all cases. In one case I want to get a set of posts with the data in the first meta field. In the second case I want to get a set of posts (the same set) but with the data in the second meta field.

I am thinking about the performance overhead of getting data I don't need and then  returning it. of course the actual hit may be quite low. Maybe it won't in fact cause more database queries. In which case maybe the answer is - that this behaviour is not supported and it doesn't matter.

If anyone has any insight into this that will be very welcome.

Comment: note that while a full response is larger than a partial response, that full response can be cached and churned out in massive numbers at speed by caching and CDN mechanisms, and even browser cache. Your bespoke couture responses that hold only the items you need may save a small amount of network bandwidth, but they force the server to generate the response from scratch each time. This can easily eliminate all time savings made transferring a few hundred characters less, especially if your site takes 1+ second to generate the API response

Comment: This is ignoring times when you need to re-request the data because you need different data. Tools such as GraphQL do this mainly because it makes development of the client side easier and automates more of the work you'd have to do at the application layer. This is why usually people query the main posts endpoint and store it locally, then use the data to generate the UI, rather than building custom endpoints that return the same data but with additional query attributes, or raw HTML